# What's the ip2md equivalent in ClrMD

Tags: windbg, sos, clrmd

I know how to iterate the object in the memory, but I'm about to do something with `ClrMD` as the `!ip2md` command in `WinDBG/SOS`. What exactly should I do?

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/clrmd/issues/6) makes me think it's not implemented at the moment. It also seems that the follow-up issues ("I'll issue standalone ticket for MT/EEClass/etc, so this one could be closed") are not follwowed up (~1 month old now and I could not find related issues). I suggest you open issue(s) for what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The source code to SOS is now open source. You can see exactly what `!ip2md` does:

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/tree/master/src/ToolBox/SOS